# Make VSCode install packages in workspace when using Modules

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have built a go app without using go modules.

I use VSCode as Editor. I have set the following in the VSCode workspace

**myapp-workspace.workspace-code**

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "."
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "go.gopath": "/Users/blah/blah/myapp/",
    "go.testFlags": ["-v"]
  }
}
```

Everything works, I can ***Install the current package*** from within the VSCode command line, as result is see the file **myapp.a** in the folder **/Users/blah/blah/myapp/bin/myapp**.

Then I decide to use **go modules**. I run the command `go mod init github.com/myuser/myapp`, and my life is not happy any more.

If I try to run ***Install the current package*** I get the error `Installation failed: $GOPATH/go.mod exists but should not`. If I remove the settings from the workspace, the package gets installed, but it is installed in **~/go/bin**.

Which is the way to configure VSCode so that it can install packages in my workspace using modules?

Comment: Is your project located in $GOPATH? Go modules suggest keeping projects outside $GOPATH

Comment: No, my project is outside $GOPATH

Answer (score 0):

Your `go.gopath` workspace setting (equivalent of `$GOPATH` for opened workspace) is pointing (I guess) to the project directory where you also have `go.mod`.

With Go modules you can't have `go.gopath` (`$GOPATH`) pointing to project directory which uses modules. If you want to use `go get` and  `go install` you need to move `go.gopath` somewhere else (it can be sub-directory in your project directory too if you prefer one GOPATH per project). Beware that might still cause problems as [some tools Visual Studio Code uses are module aware and some not](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24661).

Recommended solution when using Go modules is to switch to the new language server `gopls` which is modules aware. Here is page that tracks Go modules support in Visual Studio Code and has guide how to enable `gopls`: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Go-modules-support-in-Visual-Studio-Code